# GPIO Interface, object not callable

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font


root = Tk()
root.title("Wills Gui")
root.geometry('1400x700')
#root.configure(background='black')

def P1C():
    if B1(fg) :
        B1.fg(fg = red)
        B1["text"] = "Pin 2 Active"
        B1["fg"] = "green"
    else:
        B1.fg(fg = green)
        B1["text"] = "Pin 2 Inactive"
        B1["fg"] = "red"


B1 = Button(root, height = 8, width = 15, font="Times 12 bold", 
wraplength=80, command = P1C, text="| Q |   B1 Inactive", bg="black", 
fg="yellow").grid(row =0,column =0)

root.mainloop()
```

I have simplified the code i just need it to change the colour of the button text from green to red, etc every time it is pressed.

Comment: where it says pin2 ignore it, it should say B1 (corrected)

Comment: Can you post the full error trace for reference

Comment: \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

Comment: This is not the full trace, 'I'm trying to understand where the error originates in your code. Can you post the full trace in your question above not in comments.

Comment: ok i have simplified it as i cant run gpio commands on this pc

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/joseph/Desktop/assistance test.py", line 11, in P1C
    if B1(fg) :
NameError: name 'fg' is not defined

Comment: `B1` is always None in this code.  It's not the result of calling `Button()`, it's the result of calling `.grid()` on that Button - which doesn't return anything.  You need to do `B1.grid()` as a separate statement.

Answer (score 0):

The error is right there in the trace

```
 in P1C if B1(fg) : NameError: name 'fg' is not defined
```

The variable `fg` in the function is not defined prior to use.

Comment: but it is part of tkinter?

Comment: fg is a property of B1, it is not passed to the function in the code above

Comment: ok thanks, can you give me an example of how i would incorporate it to be a function?